# Unusual error with carousel and parralax

Tags: jquery, carousel, parallax

I am trying to debug a unusual error where when the carousel button is pushed the parallax background image flickers until the carousel has completed its movement. I am at a loss as to how to debug it.

The live version can be seen here

It is this section here. So the large image flickrs when the carousel is pressed.

I am using Chrome on Mac

Comment: It seems like a bug in chrome to me (happens in windows as well)... when animating `left` property instead of `transform` it doesn't do it. In firefox everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known bug in chrome relating to `background-attachment: fixed`. A quick fix is to set `position: static` on the effected element, in your case you would set it on `twitterbackground`

```
.twitterbackground
{
  position: static;
  ...
}
```

Comment: amazing. Chrome seems to be getting pretty buggy these days.